# How to reduce an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm building a quiz of sorts where there are no right or wrong answers, instead, answers are weighted with a score from 1-4.

Each question is assigned to one of four different categories (eg. cat, dog, rabbit, alpaca). The user's score for each question is saved to an array with the assigned category like this:

```
answersChosen = [
    {key: 'cat', value: 4},
    {key: 'dog', value: 2},
    {key: 'rabbit', value: 1},
    {key: 'alpaca', value: 3},
    {key: 'cat', value: 1},
    {key: 'dog', value: 4},
    {key: 'rabbit', value: 1},
    {key: 'alpaca', value: 2},
    {key: 'cat', value: 2},
    {key: 'dog', value: 1},
    {key: 'rabbit', value: 4},
    {key: 'alpaca', value: 3},
    {key: 'cat', value: 3},
    {key: 'dog', value: 4},
    {key: 'rabbit', value: 1},
    {key: 'alpaca', value: 2},
];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the array down to the four categories with an overall score achieved for each category in order to return the most popular animal. In this case, it would be a dog:

```
//New array
results = [
    {key: 'cat', value: 10},
    {key: 'dog', value: 11}, //highest score
    {key: 'rabbit', value: 7},
    {key: 'alpaca', value: 10},
];
```

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different approach by using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and build the wanted result set in another step.

For getting the highest score, you could reduce the array and get theobject with the max values.

```js
var answersChosen = [{ key: 'cat', value: 4 }, { key: 'dog', value: 2 }, { key: 'rabbit', value: 1 }, { key: 'alpaca', value: 3 }, { key: 'cat', value: 1 }, { key: 'dog', value: 4 }, { key: 'rabbit', value: 1 }, { key: 'alpaca', value: 2 }, { key: 'cat', value: 2 }, { key: 'dog', value: 1 }, { key: 'rabbit', value: 4 }, { key: 'alpaca', value: 3 }, { key: 'cat', value: 3 }, { key: 'dog', value: 4 }, { key: 'rabbit', value: 1 }, { key: 'alpaca', value: 2 }],
    sums = Array.from(
        answersChosen.reduce((map, { key, value }) => map.set(key, (map.get(key) || 0) + value), new Map),
        ([key, value]) => ({ key, value })
    ),
    max = sums.reduce((r, o) => {
       if (!r.length || r[0].value < o.value) return [o];
       if (r[0].value === o.value) r.push(o);
       return r;
    }, []);

console.log(sums);
console.log(max);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I get an error that reads, "Property 'push' does not exist on type '{ key: any; value: any; }'".

Comment: please check again, i changed the starting value from `undefined` to an empty array and the fist condition where `length` is checked,

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, you can map key from each element on object and add values to respective key

```js
let answersChosen = [{key: 'cat', value: 4},{key: 'dog', value: 2},{key: 'rabbit', value: 1},{key: 'alpaca', value: 3},{key: 'cat', value: 1},{key: 'dog', value: 4},{key: 'rabbit', value: 1},{key: 'alpaca', value: 2},{key: 'cat', value: 2},{key: 'dog', value: 1},{key: 'rabbit', value: 4},{key: 'alpaca', value: 3},{key: 'cat', value: 3},{key: 'dog', value: 4},{key: 'rabbit', value: 1},{key: 'alpaca', value: 2},];

let reduced = answersChosen.reduce((op,{key,value}) => {
  op[key] = op[key] || {key,value:0}
  op[key].value+= value
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(reduced))
```